# Wordpress Show Total Amount Paid After Sale

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

## In Woocommerce I want to show the total amount paid after the customer completes the payment.

**How can I do this with shortcode or adding codes to functions.php? **

I added codes to Functions.'php and copied Page.php to create payment-successful.php and added code but it didn't work. All the codes I have added are below.

functions.php
`

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'woo_title_order_received', 10, 2 );

function woo_title_order_received( $title, $id ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'is_order_received_page' ) && 
         is_order_received_page() && get_the_ID() === $id ) {
        $title = "Thank you for your order! :)";
    }
    return $title;
}
```

`

payment-successful.php
`

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit;
}


/*

Template Name: Payment

*/


?>

<div class="woocommerce-order">

        <?php if ( $order ) : ?>

                <?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

                        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

                        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
                                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>

                <?php else : ?>

                        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you for doing business with us. We have emailed you the purchase receipt for this transaction.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

                        <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                                        <?php _e( 'Transaction ID:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
                                </li>

                                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                                        <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                                        <strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
                                </li>

                                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                                        <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
                                </li>

                        </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p>Since this is your first order, we are happy to extend a 10% discount on your next purchase. Use the coupon code <strong>WELCOME10</strong> to avail the discount.</p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

`

Comment: Woocommerce have thankyou page. Edit this template instead. https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. Question on my mind, after paying by credit card, it does not redirect to the order-received page. (Redirecting order-received page in Transfer/EFT)

Comment: That probably is setting on payment method where to redirect. Most payment gateways have return url option to point to your thankyou page. Advice with your payment company.